# How to search list box without knowing what kind of objects it holds?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have ListBox and I'm binding to it a list of objects, which type will be actually on of my DataModel classes, but I want be able to know which one.
The problem is:
I want to be able to search the listBox for any item contains the keyword I want.
I know the name of property I want to search depending on it (it's the DisplayMember property).
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

I would implement a self-described ISearchable interface on your datamodel objects.

Then you can cycle through each of the items in the list box and ask the underlying object, through the interface, if it meets the search terms.

The other possibility is to use reflection to get the value from each record using the DisplayMember property, but I personally prefer the interface approach since it could be reused in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

You could have your model classes all implement an interface

```
public interface IDisplayable {
    string DisplayValue{ get; }
}
```